# Angular 7+: how to only allow upload of files with content in utf-8?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, utf-8

I am using angular 7+, I have a simple function to do the upload files and read their contents, but I would like to know how to identify the encode of document content, to only allow documents with encode utf-8.

```
async uploadFile(event) {
    var document;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    let file = event.target.files[0];

    reader.onload = ((file: any) => {
      return (e: any) => {
        document.description = e.srcElement.result;
        document.title = title;
        document.fileName = file.name;
      }
    })(file);

    reader.readAsText(file);
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Or maybe you should consider a third party library like: https://github.com/aadsm/jschardet to detect the encoding :)

Comment: It has to start by telling the users about the requirement. If your users wouldn't understand then they should not be encouraged to use text files at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the documentation of [FileReader.readAsText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText)

> instanceOfFileReader.readAsText(blob[, encoding]);

---

To ensure that the uploaded file is in UTF-8, do :

```
instanceOfFileReader.readAsText(blob, 'UTF-8');
```

Know that UTF-8 is the default setting, so it should work, you could also do :

```
instanceOfFileReader.readAsText(blob);
```

---

If the encoding is not UTF-8, the read should fail. I've seen no documentation at all about that, considering [this](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#readOperation) as the normative documentation.

You should try to upload a file having an other encoding to be sure of it.

---

There is no attribute called `encoding` or anything like it in [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText) documentation

Answer (score 0):

There is no bulletproof technique to get the encoding of a text file. Anyhow, a library called **jschardet** tries to achieve this goal though.

```js
function read(f) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(f);
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    console.log(jschardet.detect(reader.result))
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jschardet/2.1.0/jschardet.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" onchange="read(this.files[0])"></input>
```